# Converting JSON response to Model Object using Chopper library in flutter?

Tags: json, api, rest, flutter, chopper

I am using the Chopper library to invoke rest API calls.

I have followed [Raywenderlich Chopper Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10099546-elegant-networking-in-flutter-with-chopper) tutorial to implement API calls in my project.

In this tutorial, they have used the below code to convert JSON response to **Popular** model object.

```
    try {
      var mapData = json.decode(body);
      **var popular = Popular.fromJson(mapData);**
      return response.copyWith<BodyType>(body: popular as BodyType);
    } catch (e) {
      chopperLogger.warning(e);
      return response.copyWith<BodyType>(body: body);
    }
```

This is fine. But in my project, I have to make multiple API calls and need to decode multiple JSON responses to Dart model objects.

So how to decode multiple API calls responses? Do I need to do something like below:

```
      if(mapData['popularResponse'] != null) {
        Popular popularResponse = Popular.fromJson(mapData);
        return response.copyWith<BodyType>(
                  body: popularResponse as BodyType);
      } else if(mapData['articleResponse'] != null) {
        Article articleResponse = Article.fromJson(mapData);
        return response.copyWith<BodyType>(
                  body: articleResponse as BodyType);

      } else if(......) {
        ......
      }
```

How to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

One request per api file, that is the only way I see this possible, I think the http package is good enough and chopper is more trouble than its worth.